# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения

Tags: c++, указатели, дерево, неопределённое-поведение

происходит ошибка во время компиляции: Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.root было nullptr.
Нужно написать программу, которая заполняет данные о студенте, после чего нужно ввести transcript(номер) любого студента и что бы программа вывела всю информуцию о нём. Вот мой код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


typedef struct Node
{
    int transcript;
    float stiped;
    float average;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *rigth;
}Nd;

typedef Nd* ndPtr;
void instruct();
void addNode(int, float, float, ndPtr *);
void findStud(ndPtr, int);


int main()
{
    int choice, transcript;
    float stip, ave;
    choice = 0;
    transcript = 0;
    stip = 0.0;
    ave = 0.0;
    instruct();
    cin >> choice;
    ndPtr root = nullptr;

    while(choice != 3)
    { 
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter a transcript, stipend, average: " << endl;
            cin >> transcript >> stip >> ave;
            addNode(transcript, stip, ave, &root);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Enter a transcript: " << endl;
            cin >> transcript;
         findStud(root, transcript);
            break;

        }
        cout << "Enter your choice:" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }
    cout << "End ofoperation\n";
}

void instruct()
{
    cout<< "Chose the operation:\n1.Add new node\n2.Find student\n3.End ofoperation\n";
}

void addNode(int tran, float stip, float aver, ndPtr *root)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        ndPtr item = new Node;
        item->transcript = tran;
        item->stiped = stip;
        item->average = aver;

        item->left = NULL;
        item->rigth = NULL;

        *root = item;
    }
    else
    {
        ndPtr item = *root;
        if (tran < item->transcript)
            addNode(tran, stip, aver, &item->left);
        if(tran > item->transcript)
            addNode(tran, stip, aver, &item->rigth);

    }
}

void findStud(ndPtr root, int a)
{
    if (root->transcript == a)
    {
        cout << root->transcript << " " << root->stiped << " " << root->average;
        return;
    }

    if (root->transcript > a )
    {
        return findStud(root->rigth, a);
    }

    if (root->transcript < a)
    {
        return findStud(root->left, a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Исключения программ не возникают во время компиляции. Постарайтесь сами отладить программу, если вы ее сами написали.

Comment: На какой строчке хоть падает расскажите

Comment: @llll В функции  findStud нет проверки на то, что указатель на головной узел равен  nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

Исключения программ не возникают во время их компиляции. У вас типичное исключение времени выполнения программы, говорящее о том, что переменная `root` равна `nullptr`.

В функции

```
void findStud(ndPtr root, int a)
{
    if (root->transcript == a)
    {
        cout << root->transcript << " " << root->stiped << " " << root->average;
        return;
    }

    if (root->transcript > a )
    {
        return findStud(root->rigth, a);
    }

    if (root->transcript < a)
    {
        return findStud(root->left, a);
    }
}
```

нет проверки на то,, равен ли  указатель `root` значению `nullptr`. А потому в случае отсутствия значения  переменной `a` в дереве, функция имеет неопределенное поведение.

Вам следует переписать функцию хотя бы следующим образом, то есть когда она возвращает узел найденного студента в дереве, либо `nullptr` если такой студент не найден.

Например,

```
ndPtr findStud(ndPtr root, int a)
{
    if ( !root || root->transcript == a )
    {
        return root;
    }
    else if (root->transcript > a )
    {
        return findStud(root->rigth, a);
    }
    else
    {
        return findStud(root->left, a);
    }
}
```

И уж затем, получив указатель на узел после вызова функции, либо выводить информацию о студенте, либо сообщить, что такой студент не найден.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct Node
{
    int transcript;
    float stiped;
    float average;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *rigth;
}Nd;

typedef Nd* ndPtr;

void addNode(int, float, float, ndPtr *);
ndPtr findStud(ndPtr, int);

void addNode(int tran, float stip, float aver, ndPtr *root)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        ndPtr item = new Node;
        item->transcript = tran;
        item->stiped = stip;
        item->average = aver;

        item->left = NULL;
        item->rigth = NULL;

        *root = item;
    }
    else
    {
        ndPtr item = *root;
        if (tran < item->transcript)
            addNode(tran, stip, aver, &item->left);
        if(tran > item->transcript)
            addNode(tran, stip, aver, &item->rigth);

    }
}

ndPtr findStud(ndPtr root, int a)
{
    if ( !root || root->transcript == a )
    {
        return root;
    }
    else if (root->transcript > a )
    {
        return findStud(root->rigth, a);
    }
    else
    {
        return findStud(root->left, a);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    ndPtr root = nullptr;

    addNode( 1, 10.01f, 20.02f, &root );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    {
        ndPtr target = findStud( root, i );

        if ( target == nullptr )
        {
            std::cout << "Student #" << i << " has not been found.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Student #" << i << ": "
                      << target->stiped << ", "
                      <<  target->average << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Student #0 has not been found.
Student #1: 10.01, 20.02
```

Также имейте в виду, что вводить такой алиас типа для указателя

```
typedef Nd* ndPtr;
```

это плохая идея. В этом случае вам не удастся объявить указатель на константный объект, используя этот алиас, так как, например, `const ndPtr` означает `Nd * const`, а не `const Nd *`.

А функцию `findStud` желательно объявить, используя указатель на константный объект, так как эта функция не изменяет узлы дерева. То есть функцию следовало бы объявить как

```
const Nd * findStud( const Nd *, int);
```

а алиас `ndPtr` в этом отношении не помогает.